# connect to mail server from java over tls doesn't check certificate

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, sslsocketfactory

trying to connect a mail server over TLS with a certificate but the connection success even I put a wrong certificate.
 I add these properties:

```
 javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth",true);
 javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.timeout", "8500");
 javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
 javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory", sslSocketFactory);
 javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", true);
```

the way I created the socket factory:
( I created new key store with the public certifucate from the server. and creted the socketfctory)

```
private MailSSLSocketFactory getMailSSLSocketFactory(String certificate){
        try {
            logger.debug("Start, getting mail ssl socket factory");
            KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore(certificate);
            KeyManager[] keyManagers = getKeyManagers(keyStore);
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = getTrustManagers(keyStore);

            MailSSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getMailSSLSocketFactory(keyManagers, trustManagers);
            logger.debug("End, getting mail ssl socket factory");
            return sslSocketFactory;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private KeyStore getKeyStore(String certificate) throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream certificateStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificateStream);

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("smtp.certificate", x509Certificate);
        return keyStore;
    }

    private KeyManager[] getKeyManagers(KeyStore keyStore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, null);
        return keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
    }

    private TrustManager[] getTrustManagers(KeyStore keyStore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
        return trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    }

    private MailSSLSocketFactory getMailSSLSocketFactory(KeyManager[] keyManagers, TrustManager[] trustManagers) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        MailSSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        sslSocketFactory.setKeyManagers(keyManagers);
        sslSocketFactory.setTrustManagers(trustManagers);
        return sslSocketFactory;
    }
```

what did I miss or wrong?

Comment: Where is mail.smtp.socketFactory.port  and did you implement javax.net.SocketFactory interface in your socketFactory class?

Comment: @Sirsendu many thanks for the answer. do I have to put a port for the socketFactory? I put the port in the JavaMailSender, it shouldn't be different, is it?

Comment: @Sirsendu regarding the implementation of the SocketFaoctory, I didn't implement it. should I ? can you give an example?

Comment: first of all, let me tell you that Properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");** 

and

Properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");, been outdated as per http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq-135477.html#commonmistakes . The simplified one is properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true"); Is that not worked?

Comment: @Sirsendu you say that I shouldn't Use the properties of SocketFactory? where should I put the certificate? how does it know not to trust all?

Comment: can you show me the code of your socketFactory class?

Comment: It trusts the same certificates that the JDK trusts, based on known certificate authorities.  You can enable additional checks by setting the [`mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity) property.  And as mentioned above, [get rid of all that socket factory stuff](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).